# Is the CSS3 End's with $ function affected by a user's sid?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add style to a particular link and have currently used the * universal `[attr*="value"]`, which in my case is:

```
a[href*="&kasse=1"]:link
```

I would like to use:

```
a[href$="&kasse=1"]:link
```

However, the link I would like to use this for often has an sid attached to it.  Does the $ apply to the link itself or the link with the sid attached to the end?

eg:

```
&kasse
```

OR

```
&kasse=1&sid=ec5790d14cb5f45a746fec04f2833e64
```

Basically the question is can I ignore the sid, or do I have to allow for it?
Am I right in thinking that the href attribute is an HTML attribute and therefore only applies to the HTML, and sid is not HTML (but PHP???)?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest having a look at your rendered markup, and see what the href becomes. Also, I don't actually see an a tag in your question?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say..

Comment: looks like you want to use it with some parameter in URL e.g. Kasse?

Comment: why would you like to use the `$` - attribute selector? This has a look at the end, the suffix, of the attributes value. The contains (`*`) selector that you are already using seems perfect for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not match that.

Try with the contains selector `*=`

```
a[href*="&kasse=1"]:link
```

---

It doesn't matter what the `sid` means conceptually. Since it is added in the html code (*as part of the `href` attribute*) it will cause the CSS rule to fail, as it matches the actual string in the html.

---

Alternatively you could do (*assuming that if the `sid` will always be the last part in the `href`*)

```
a[href$="&kasse=1"]:link, /*will match ending with &kasse=1*/
a[href*="&kasse=1&sid="]:link { /*will match &kasse=17sid anywhere in the href*/

}
```

Comment: OK, thank you.  I wanted to use the $= because the phrase "&kasse=1" appears in the middle of another link.  I don't have access to the sids so will just have to use the *= method

Comment: if the `&kasse=1` appear only in the end or in the middle but without the `sid` after it you could combine two rules. updated answer

Comment: Ahh, thank you! totally simple, I will use the second one as I actually only want the style to apply to the one where the phrase "&kasse=1&sid=" is at the end and not in the middle!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be a little confused so below is an example of the two outcomes. Hopefully with this it should help you diagnose which you would need.

```css
a[href$="&kasse=1"]:link  {
  color:red;
}

a[href*="&kasse=1"]:link  {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<a href="?test=1&kasse=1">First</a><br />
<a href="?test=1&kasse=1&sid=reDF3fWEFwhhd3e2hh0">Second</a>
```

Quite simply, the CSS selector matches what is in the `href` attribute on the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

by using a[href$="&kasse=1"]:link your selector search for link ends with &Klasse=1

```
a[href*="&kasse=1"]:link  is the right one

= is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= is starts with
$= is ends with
*= is contains
~= is contains word
|= is starts with prefix (i.e., |= "prefix" matches "prefix-...")
```